# Available resources for learning WordPress 4.7.2 from the ground up?

Tags: wp-admin, admin

My workplace is about to move to a swanky WordPress site from our ancient, never-upgraded ExpressionEngine site. I'm pretty good at hand-coding HTML for basic formatting, and I've watched about 6 hours' worth of "Creating a Wordpress site from scratch" videos on YouTube, including the specific themes and plug-ins we're getting (X, Integrity Stack, a few other bells and whistles).

Now that I have my feet wet, and more-or-less know my way around Cornerstone and the Inspector, I was hoping to find something like Codecademy or Scotch.io with actual hands-on training/experimentation, but so far I've come up short.

What tools and resources exist (if any) to allow a WordPress developer (especially a relative newb like me) to learn the functionality in a sandbox-like environment?

[Note: this is obviously similar to [Resources for a complete beginner to learn to work professionally with Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34505/resources-for-a-complete-beginner-to-learn-to-work-professionally-with-wordpress), but that was 6 years ago with no recent updates. If you'd prefer to close this question and update that one with updated data, I'd understand.]

Comment: https://knowthecode.io/ (I have no affiliation with Know the Code)

Comment: At first I thought it was all for-pay, but I found this resource deeper down: https://knowthecode.io/series/absolute-beginner-series. Thanks for the recommendation... this looks solid!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) of the official page, try creating a Theme using all of the features that are there, each one comes with example code, try copy pasting and adapting it to your theme.

The same with the [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) try creating a plugin, reading the [blog](https://wordpress.org/news/) is good too, specially the [development category](https://wordpress.org/news/category/development/), you can see how WordPress evolved and what new features and changes occurred.

Like in the post you mentioned the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) and the [actual code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser) are still a resource, i would add to it the [developer search](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=), which is great to search for function, classess, methods, hooks etc.

Comment: Awesome...I've been to the official page a lot, but totally missed these resources! Thanks!